# Create a square from user inputs

Tags: javascript, css

I am attempting to create a square from user inputs.

I thought that having having the height and width in my style multiplied together would create the square after clicking my button.

My question is: How do I get the user inputs to be used for the height and width of the box?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="width">
<input type="text" id="height">
    
<button onclick="calculate()">Click Me For Square</button>
<br>
<p id="box"></p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    function calculate() {
        var w = document.getElementById("width").value;
        var h = document.getElementById("height").value;
        box = document.getElementById("box");
        box.innerHTML = " " + (w*h);
    }
    
    var square = document.createElement('div');
        square.className = 'square';
        document.body.appendChild(square);
```

**Style**

```
 background: red;
  width: (h*w);
  height: (w*h);
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

Comment: Your style rule has no selector and css knows nothing about your javascript variables like `h` and `w`. Also height and width require units of measurement in css

Comment: Do some research into how to change an element's css with javascript, then use what you find to set your box element's `width` and `height` css properties to your `w` and `h` variables.

Answer (score 0):

set `square.style.width/height` with the input values like below demo:

```js
function calculate() {
    var w = document.getElementById("width").value;
    var h = document.getElementById("height").value;
    box = document.getElementById("box");
    box.innerHTML = " " + (w*h);
    document.querySelectorAll('div.square').forEach(item => item.remove())
    var square = document.createElement('div');
        square.className = 'square';
        square.style.width = w + 'px' // width
        square.style.height = h + 'px' // height
        document.body.appendChild(square);
}
```

```css
.square {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="width" value="25">
<input type="text" id="height" value="25">
    
<button onclick="calculate()">Click Me For Square</button>
<br>
<p id="box"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is There any way to remove the previous square?

Would using some sort of loop do the trick?

Comment: one simple solution is uses `queryselectorAll` to get all of `div.square` then remove them before add new square.